# Wireless mouse not working in USB HUB, but works in laptop USB port

Tags: 16.04, usb

I am new user of Ubuntu 16.04 (installed on USB 3.0 stick) and I have come across a problem when none of my wireless mouses (Trust, HP, Microsoft) works on my recently bought USB HUB Tracer H7. My phone seems to work just fine when plugged into it as well as do regular wired mouses. All mouses are also displayed when I check `lsusb` regardless of where they are plugged. The best I managed was with the Microsoft mouse, after pressing the synching button on the adapter, I got the cursor to jerk around a bit, but even that stopped working after a short while.

All help, suggestions or insights you could provide are very welcome.